# How to select values based on several condtions: SUM for one range if met then sum for another range

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, data-analysis

I have a table with columns like `countries, year, values`.

I need to find countries where the sum of their values between 2015 and 2018 is 0 and between 2019 and 2022 is greater than 1.

I tried to use a subquery but that didn't work for me:

```
SELECT countries 
FROM diamonds_export_long 
WHERE year BETWEEN '2015' AND '2018'
GROUP BY countries, year
HAVING SUM(value_millions) = 0
```

This gave the result partly, then I tried to use it as subquery didn't work

```
SELECT countries
FROM diamonds_export_long 
GROUP BY countries, year
HAVING (year BETWEEN '2015' AND '2018' AND SUM(value_millions) = 0)
   AND (year BETWEEN '2019' AND '2021' AND SUM(value_millions) > 1)
```

This looks more in the right way but doesn't return any results.

Maybe the solution by using case

Comment: Do not group by `year`. Move all you conditions into `HAVING` clause using `and` and `or` appropriately.

Comment: It looks like its too many conditions not sure if i did it right but it find no data                     
select 
countries 
 FROM diamonds_export_long 
 GROUP BY countries ,year
  having  (year between '2015' and '2018' and  sum(value_millions) = 0)
    and (year between '2019' and '2021'and sum(value_millions) > 1)

Comment: It should be `or` between main conditions. Is your criteria based on annual sums for each year in the range or the entire range total?

Comment: the problem is i need to sum it twice based on different years

Comment: annual sum for entire range  , and if the first conditon is met then it should check the result for the second condition

Comment: I understand now. You may want to [edit] your question and put all your clarifications inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need *conditional aggregation*.

Below is **untested** code to be used as a guideline.

```
SELECT
  countries, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN year between 2015 
    and 2018 THEN value_millions ELSE 0 END
  ) as sum15_18, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN year between 2019 
    and 2022 THEN value_millions ELSE 0 END
  ) as sum19_22 
FROM 
  diamonds_export_long 
WHERE 
  (
    year between 2015 
    and 2018 
    OR year between 2019 
    and 2022
  ) -- optional 
GROUP BY 
  countries 
having 
  sum15_18 = 0 
  and sum19_22 > 1
```